# Plug in or pattern for dealing with large forms in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with a number of inputs, and I want to collect the values of the inputs in my state, without having to define an `onChange` or custom component for each input.

React has an official add-on `LinkedStatesMixin` that seems to be on its way out, and is only a partial solution (missing radio button groups, for example):

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2302

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3573

Meanwhile coming from Angular and Ember, an elegant and concise API for setting up input bindings is a must-have feature in a front-end framework.

What's the most React-ish way to accomplish this without using the deprecated `LinkedStatesMixin`?

Answer (score 2):

We built custom bindings for this. See here: http://blog.sendsonar.com/2015/08/04/angular-like-deep-path-data-bindings-in-react/

The article we wrote also references ReactLink (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) which is probably what you're using with LinkedStatesMixin, but the docs do have a section on how to use ReactLink without LinkedStatesMixin, hope that helps?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it. This is from https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns React.13.Common/FormInputs.

jInput.js

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class JInputRender extends Component {
        binder(...methods) { methods.forEach( (method) => this[method] = this[method].bind(this) ); }

        render() {
            var inputSty = this.props.input.style ? this.props.input.style : {color: 'red'};
            var textValue = this.state.textValue;
            var colorValue = this.props.input.colorValue ? this.props.input.colorValue : '#1A3212';
            var checkedValue = (this.props.input.checkedValue != null) ? this.props.input.checkedValue : false;
            var numberValue = this.props.input.numberValue ? this.props.input.numberValue : 0;
            var radioValue = this.props.input.radioValue ? this.props.input.radioValue : '';
            var radioChecked = (this.props.input.radioChecked != null) ? this.props.input.radioChecked : false;
            var min = this.props.input.min ? this.props.input.min : 0;
            var max = this.props.input.max ? this.props.input.max : 100;
            var step = this.props.input.step ? this.props.input.step : 1;
            var inputType = this.props.input.type ? this.props.input.type : 'text';

            var returnRadio = (
                    <input
                        type={inputType}
                        ref='inputRef'
                        style={inputSty}
                        checked={radioChecked}
                        value={radioValue}
                        onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
                )

            var returnChecked = (
                    <input
                        type={inputType}
                        ref='inputRef'
                        style={inputSty}
                        checked={checkedValue}
                        onChange={this.handleCheckedChange} />
                )

            var returnColor = (
                    <input
                        type={inputType}
                        ref='inputRef'
                        style={inputSty}
                        value={colorValue}
                        onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
                )

            var returnNumber = (
                    <input
                        type={inputType}
                        ref='inputRef'
                        style={inputSty}
                        value={numberValue}
                        min={min} max={max} step={step}
                        onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
                )

            var returnText = (
                    <input
                        type={inputType}
                        ref='inputRef'
                        style={inputSty}
                        value={textValue}
                        onChange={this.handleTextValueChange} />
                )
            var returnIt;
            switch (inputType) {
                case 'checkbox': returnIt = returnChecked; break;
                case 'radio': returnIt = returnRadio; break;
                case 'color': returnIt = returnColor; break;
                case 'number':
                case 'range': returnIt = returnNumber; break;
                default: returnIt = returnText; break;
            }

            return (returnIt);
        }
    }

    export default class JInput extends JInputRender {
        constructor() {
          super();
            this.state = {textValue: ''};
          this.binder('handleCheckedChange', 'handleTextValueChange', 'handleValueChange');
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            if (this.props.input.textValue) this.setState({textValue: this.props.input.textValue});
            if (this.props.input.focus) React.findDOMNode(this.refs.inputRef).focus();
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if (nextProps.input.textValue && (this.state.textValue != nextProps.input.textValue))
                {this.setState({textValue: nextProps.input.textValue});}
        }
        handleCheckedChange(event) { this.props.handleChange(this.props.input.name, event.target.checked); }
        handleTextValueChange(event) {
            var newValue = event.target.value;
            this.setState({textValue: newValue});
            this.props.handleChange(this.props.input.name, newValue);
        }
        handleValueChange(event) { this.props.handleChange(this.props.input.name, event.target.value); }
    }
```

app.ctrl.js. Just skip the JRadioGroup stuff.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    import Actions from './../flux/Actions';
    import JInput from './common/jInput';
    import JRadioGroup from './common/jRadioGroup';

    import BasicStore from './../flux/Basic.Store';

    var AppCtrlSty = {
        height: '100%',
        padding: '0 10px 0 0'
    }

    var checkBoxSty = {
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        display: 'inline-block',
        lineHeight: '18px',
        marginLeft: '2px',
        outline: 'none',
        position: 'relative'
    };

    var radioSty = {color: "blue"}

    var input3Sty = {color: 'green'};

    var inputLabel = {margin: '0 5px'};

    var textInput1 = {name: 'text', type: 'text', textValue: '', focus: true};
    var checkInput1 = {name: 'checkbox', type: 'checkbox', style: checkBoxSty};
    var colorInput = {name: 'color', type: 'color'};
    var numberInput = {name: 'number', type: 'number', min: 0, max: 100};
    var rangeInput = {name: 'range', type: 'range', min: 0, max: 100};

    var radioInput1 = {name: 'radioGroup', type: 'radio', radioValue: 'set'};
    var radioInput2 = {name: 'radioGroup', type: 'radio', radioValue: 'setkey'};
    var radioInput3 = {name: 'radioGroup', type: 'radio', radioValue: 'key'};

    class AppCtrlRender extends Component {
        binder(...methods) { methods.forEach( (method) => this[method] = this[method].bind(this) ); }

        render() {
            var inputData = this.state.data;

            textInput1.textValue = inputData.text;
            checkInput1.checkedValue = inputData.checkbox;
            colorInput.colorValue = inputData.color;
            numberInput.numberValue = inputData.number;
            rangeInput.numberValue = inputData.range;

            radioInput1.radioChecked = inputData.radioGroup == 'set';
            radioInput2.radioChecked = inputData.radioGroup == 'setkey';
            radioInput3.radioChecked = inputData.radioGroup == 'key';

            var selected = inputData.checkbox ? 'true' : 'false';
            var radioGroupName1 = 'key1'; //must be distinct for each use of JRadioGroup
            var radioValue = inputData.radioGroup;
            return (
                <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
                    React 1.3 Form input<br/><br/>
                    Text: <JInput input={textInput1} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /><br/><br/>
                    Checkbox: <JInput input={checkInput1} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Value: {selected}<br/><br/>
                    Color: <JInput input={colorInput} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Value: {colorInput.colorValue}<br/><br/>
                    Number: <JInput input={numberInput} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Value: {numberInput.numberValue}<br/><br/>
                    Range: <JInput input={rangeInput} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Value: {rangeInput.numberValue}<br/><br/>
              <JRadioGroup name={radioGroupName1} value={radioValue} ref="keyGroup" onChange={this.handleRadioChange}>
                <div>Radio Group:
                  <label id='inputLabel1' style={inputLabel}>
                    <input type="radio" value="set" /> Set
                  </label>
                  <label id='inputLabel2' style={inputLabel}>
                    <input type="radio" value="setkey"/> Set/Key
                  </label>
                  <label id='inputLabel3' style={inputLabel}>
                    <input type="radio" value="key"/> Key
                  </label>
                </div>
              </JRadioGroup><br/><br/>

                    Radio Input: &nbsp;
                    <JInput input={radioInput1} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Set &nbsp;
                    <JInput input={radioInput2} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Set/Key &nbsp;
                    <JInput input={radioInput3} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Key &nbsp;
                    Value: {radioValue}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    function getState() { return {data: BasicStore.getData()}; };

    export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {
        constructor() {
          super();
            this.state = getState();
          this.binder('storeDidChange', 'handleValueChange', 'handleRadioChange');
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.unsubscribe = BasicStore.listen(this.storeDidChange);
        }
        componentWillUnmount() { this.unsubscribe(); }
        storeDidChange() { this.setState(getState()); }
      handleRadioChange(event) { Actions.editRecord('type', event.target.value); }
        handleValueChange(name, value) { Actions.editRecord(name, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [Redux](https://rackt.github.io/redux/) to manage states, and with [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) middleware to manage form fields. It stores the form states in the root state, so you can just get all the values at once.

If you don't want to use Redux, you can try modify [this](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/blob/master/src/linkClass.js) to automatically hook up every input element in your component, and write a decorator like [this](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/blob/master/src/index.js) to apply to your components. However it's dirty and I don't recommend doing so.

Comment: Do you have any examples or snippets of your implementation that you wouldn't mind showing? Trying to grasp Redux and React forms has been a little dizzying. :/