# React slow with multiple controlled text inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with multiple text inputs. I have them all set up as controlled inputs. When typing, there is a lag of up to several seconds for the new text to display in the field. Here is an example field:

```
<label>Event Name</label>
<input type="text" 
       placeholder="Title"
       className="form-control"
       name="title"
       value={this.state.event.title}
       onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

I can't figure out what's causing it to be so slow or what to do to fix it.

UPDATED: Here's the component, should be enough to show what's going on.

```
let CreateEventForm = React.createClass({
  submit: function () {},
  handleChange: function(e){
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    if(value === 'true'){
      value = true;
    }
    if(value === 'false'){
      value = false;
    }
    // If true/false toggle old
    let oldState = this.state.event[name];
    if(typeof oldState === 'boolean'){
      value = !oldState;
    }
    // If is array
    if(name.indexOf('[]') > -1){
      name = name.replace('[]', '');
      oldState = this.state.event[name];
      var pos = oldState.indexOf(value);
      if(pos > -1){
        oldState.splice(pos, 1);
      } else {
        oldState.push(value);
      }
      value = oldState;
    }
    let event = this.state.event;
    event[name] = value;
    this.setState({event: event});
    console.log(this.state.event);
  },
  getClasses(field, additionalClasses = []) {
    // If a string is passed for additional class, make array
    if(!Array.isArray(additionalClasses)){
      additionalClasses = [additionalClasses];
    }
    let useDefaultColumns = additionalClasses.filter(function(className){
        return className.indexOf('col-') > -1;
      }).length === 0;
    let hasError = function(){
      let fields = Array.isArray(field) ? field : [field];
      return fields.filter(function(field){
          return !this.props.isValid(field);
        }.bind(this)).length > 0;
    }.bind(this)();
    return classnames({
      'col-sm-4': useDefaultColumns,
      'form-group': true,
      'has-error': hasError
    }, additionalClasses);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form ref="eventForm" onSubmit={this.submit}>
        <SavedModal isOpen={this.state.saved} reset={this.resetForm} style={this.state.modals.styles} />
        <h3>Info</h3>

        <div className="row">
          <div className={this.getClasses('title')}>
            <label>Event Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title"
                   className="form-control"
                   name="title"
                   value={this.state.event.title}
                   onChange={this.handleChange} />
            {this.renderHelpText(this.props.getValidationMessages('title'))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className={this.getClasses('type')}>
            <label>Event Type</label>
            <select name="type"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={this.state.event.type}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    onBlur={this.props.handleValidation('type')}>
              <option value="">Select Event Type&hellip;</option>
              {this.state.calendarTypes.map(function (type, key) {
                return <option value={type.name} key={key}>{type.name}</option>
              })}
            </select>
            {this.renderHelpText(this.props.getValidationMessages('type'))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Duration</h3>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="form-group col-sm-2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="allDay" checked={this.state.event.allDay} onChange={this.handleChange}/> All Day
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="form-group col-sm-2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="repeats" checked={this.state.event.repeats} onChange={this.handleChange}/> Repeats&hellip;
          </div>
          <br/><br/>
        </div>

        <h3>Location</h3>
        <div className="row">
          <div className={this.getClasses('location')}>
            <select name="location"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={this.state.event.location}
                    onBlur={this.props.handleValidation('location')}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <option value="">Select a Location&hellip;</option>
              {this.state.locations.map(function (location, key) {
                return (
                  <option value={location.name} key={key}>{location.name}</option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
            {this.renderHelpText(this.props.getValidationMessages('location'))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Description</h3>
        <div className="row">
          <div className={this.getClasses('description')}>
            <label>Write a description:</label>
            <textarea className="form-control"
                      name="description"
                      value={this.state.event.description}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      onBlur={this.props.handleValidation('description')}
                      rows="10"></textarea>
            {this.renderHelpText(this.props.getValidationMessages('description'))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Event Details</h3>
        <div className="row">
          <div className={this.getClasses('fee')}>
            <label>Fee:</label>
            <input type="text"
                   className="form-control"
                   name="fee"
                   value={this.state.event.fee}
                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                   onBlur={this.props.handleValidation('fee')}/>
            {this.renderHelpText(this.props.getValidationMessages('fee'))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
              Create Event
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: We can't either without a complete example.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, I've updated it with more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as this still gets responses, thought I'd update this and close it. Calling `handleChange` within `onChange` would cause the entire form to rerender on every change, thereby slowing it down. If you had a simple form you could just update `onBlur` instead or create individual input components so the rerender would be isolated to that one input. Personally, I use and would recommend using [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) for building forms as it abstracts this complexity for you.

Answer (score 25):

I had a similar situation and my solution was to disable React Dev Tools. They were affecting input fields somehow. The problem is it's not enough to refresh a page if you have clicked React Dev Tools tab. They are still affecting your inputs. You have to open new page to stop them. You can also remove them from Chrome completely but I don't recommend doing this 'cause they are useful. :)

Comment: Thanks for this, I had this issue happening intermittently and yep, it was the dev tools...They need to include a disconnect option in the tools....

Comment: This really helped things for me, the underlying problem is still there and I'll have to fix it by refactoring my component and adding `shouldComponentUpdate`, but for now it's ok.

Answer (score 16):

There are many possible reasons for this to happen. I faced the similar issue and filtered the main cause to:

- Large State, so it takes up sometime
- React Dev Tool / Use of non minified react
- Mutating state data

Whatever may be the reason, I found a quick fix for this. If you just want to store it to the state but not using it for live rendering. Then you can safely replace the 'onChange' to 'onBlur'. This has no dealay and lag. If you know any other case where this will not work, do let me know!

Change the code as follow:

```
<label>Event Name</label>
<input 
   type="text" 
   placeholder="Title"
   className="form-control"
   name="title"
   value={this.state.event.title}
   onBlur={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: you should use defaultValue instead of value, so you can change input value when you input something.

Comment: Hi @Frank , I tried that and it doesn't work in case I want to use the form for edit. While the edit data arrives via ajax, the initial value is rendered.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example for an input pattern, [Plug in or pattern for dealing with large forms in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729192/plug-in-or-pattern-for-dealing-with-large-forms-in-react/32830828#32830828). The main thing is to have your input as a component that passes changes to the parent but doesn't update from the props if they are the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks Janaka. I was thinking that would complicate managing state but I guess it should at least prevent unnecessary DOM rerenders.

Comment: This would add more overhead to the component as it will do lots of comparision operations. For e.g. onKeyUp event of a textbox or text area.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that my state object was complex and thus causing rendering issues. My solution was to manage the state of the notes in my component, then on blur update the container state.

```
const { data, onEdit } = props;
const { containerNotes } = data;

const [notes, setNotes] = useState('');

useEffect(
  () => {
    setNotes(containerNotes);
  },
  [containerNotes],
);

const onChangeNotes = () => ({ target: { value } }) => {
  setNotes(value);
};

const onBlurNotes = (prop) => ({ target: { value } }) => {
  const newData = update(data, {
    [prop]: { $set:  value },
  });
  onEdit(newData);
};

return (
  <input 
     type="text" 
     placeholder="Title"
     name="title"
     value={notes}
     onChange={onChangeNotes()}
     onBlur={onBlurNotes('containerNotes')}
 />
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fix I found. It sets the parent state in onBlur. Please vet this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MUIField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.defaultValue);
  const prop = _.omit(props, ['onChange', 'value', 'defaultValue']);

  return (
      <MUIField {...prop} value={value}
                onChange={e => { setValue(e.target.value); }}
                onBlur={() => {
                  props.onChange({ target:{ value }});
              }}/>);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `React-Hook-Form` is great at minimising re-renders, and probably optimise performance. I have yet to try it though.

Answer (score 0):

I've had redux logger middleware take enough time to create this input lag. So, try disabling that as well.

Answer (score 0):

useRef instead, it doesn't re-render

```js
const App = () => {
  const textRef = useRef();
  const showRefContent = () => {
    console.log(textRef.current.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField inputRef={textRef} />
      <button onClick={showRefContent}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```